# Background with multiple data

Tags: cucumber-java

I have 2 username and password combination and I have a scenario after that.I want to login with username1,password1 and complete the scenario and then want to login with username2,password2 and complete the scenario.I have defined login in background.Is this possible in cucumber?Any inputs will be helpfull.TIA..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible according to [cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background).

You can only have one set of Background steps per feature. If you need different Background steps for different scenarios, you’ll need to split them into different feature files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the same scenario with different inputs, you can use [Scenario outline](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline) and use the first username & password in the first Example, and the second in the second Example.

If that is your question, I wonder why you want to rerun the same Scenario with a different username and password? Do the different users have different roles for example and both should be able to do something? Consider whether each scenario / example illustrates a particular **behaviour** in your application.

Comment: Can scenario outline be used with Background?